# How to disable or fix GTK scrolling indicators?

Tags: cinnamon, gtk, theme

I'm using Ambiance theme on Fedora 22 with Cinnamon and some windows have opaque scrolling indicators that cover bottom part of windows:

[image]

Can i somehow disable scrolling indicators?
Alternatively, how can i edit theme and make indicators transparent?

Comment: What do you mean by "scrolling indicators"? The scrollbar? I'm pretty sure they're not supposed to cover the contents of the window.

Comment: @Wieland Take a look at the screenshot. There are 40 pixel wide gray blocks next to the scrollbars. They are supposed to be semi-transparent gradients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more research i have found out that those indicators are called overshoot and undershoot.

[Related ticket](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-themes/+bug/1449515):

> In GTK 3.16 (for example from ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ww),
>   GtkScrolledWindows indicate whether there is content that can be
>   scrolled to (Adwaita shows a dashed line for this) and if the user
>   scrolls when there is no more content (Adwaita shows a gradient
>   thing). These are called undershoot and overshoot respectively.
>
> Ambiance and Radiance don't style these classes, and the default is to
>   show an opaque grey area. This looks poor.

To fix issue on fedora with `light-gtk3-theme v14.04` i added this CSS to /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk-widgets.css:

```
/*************
 * overshoot *
 *************/
.overshoot.top {
    background: -gtk-gradient(radial, center top, 0, center top, 0.7, from(shade(@bg_color, 0.92)), to(alpha(@bg_color, 0.0)));
}

.overshoot.right {
    background: -gtk-gradient(radial, right center, 0, right center, 0.7, from(shade(@bg_color, 0.92)), to(alpha(@bg_color, 0.0)));
}

.overshoot.bottom {
    background: -gtk-gradient(radial, center bottom, 0, center bottom, 0.7, from(shade(@bg_color, 0.92)), to(alpha(@bg_color, 0.0)));
}

.overshoot.left {
    background: -gtk-gradient(radial, left center, 0, left center, 0.7, from(shade(@bg_color, 0.92)), to(alpha(@bg_color, 0.0)));
}

/**************
 * undershoot *
 **************/
.undershoot {
    background: none;
}
```

See [revision 436](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-art-pkg/ubuntu-themes/trunk/revision/436) for Radiance CSS.